# CURL "Expected token ')', got '__typeof__'" in QT

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I'm developing a program that is supposed to download a file from a site in QT, but since the default QT libraries didn't work, I have decided to use CURL instead. Following one of the examples on the documentation portion of their site, I have come up with the following code:

downloader.h

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

// Curl includes
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "curl/types.h"
#include "curl/easy.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class Downloader : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Downloader();
    void DownloadFile(QString url, QString directory);

signals:
    void DownloadProgress(int downloaded, int total, QString message);
    void DownloadComplete();

private:
    void downProg(double t, double d, double ultotal, double ulnow);
    void read(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
    void write(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

downloader.cpp

```
#include "downloader.h"

// Curl includes
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

Downloader::Downloader()
{

}

void Downloader::DownloadFile(QString url, QString directory) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *outFile;
    //gchar *url = ptr;
    QString outFileName = directory + "/tempDL/minecraft.jar";

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        outFile = fopen(outFileName.toLocal8Bit().data(), "w");

        char *urlC = url.toLocal8Bit().data();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlC);
    }
}

void Downloader::downProg(double t, double d, double ultotal, double ulnow) {

}

void Downloader::read(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {

}

void Downloader::write(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {

}
```

Even before building, QT Creator tells me when I hover over the line: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlC);` the following: `expected token ')' got '__typeof__'`

Then, when compiling the program, I get a `collect2: Id returned 1 exit status`

After Googling around a little, I have a suspicion that it might be some kind of define statement, but I couldn't find a solution after removing them from my class.

And this is my last resort for a file downloader, so I really need to make this work.

**Edit:**

After reviewing the Compiler Output, I found the following. I thought it might help:

```
WARNING: Failure to find: Fetcher/http_fetcher.h

WARNING: Failure to find: Fetcher/http_error_codes.h

WARNING: Failure to find: Fetcher/http_fetcher.h

WARNING: Failure to find: Fetcher/http_error_codes.h
```

And, after commenting out the problematic bits of code, the collect2 error seems to be caused because of this line of code:

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

**Update:**

After fooling around with this for days, it has done nothing but frustrate me. I've decided to just try and get the default QT functions to work again instead of fooling with getting this to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I actually doubt these two things are related; the message from Creator (which by the way says 'ld' and not 'Id' :) implies that compilation actually succeeded, at least up to the point that linking was attempted.  The error message on mouse hover may be a limitation of Creator's C++ parser?  Please paste the full compilation log from Creator (you may have to switch tabs to find it).

Comment: The two are definitely unrelated. The first is from a C++ parser, the second from a linker.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to diagnose this issue is to do a 'preprocess-only' compilation. I assume you're using G++ so you should try the `-E` switch and output to a file. Then take a look at the file to see what the `curl_easy_setopt` line looks like.

**UPDATE:** For QT creator you could save off the temporary files created during compilation by updating your .pro file to include this option:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -save-temps`

From the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html):

> Store the usual “temporary”
>   intermediate files permanently; place
>   them in the current directory and name
>   them based on the source file. Thus,
>   compiling foo.c with `-c -save-temps'
>   would produce files foo.i and foo.s,
>   as well as foo.o. This creates a
>   preprocessed foo.i output file even
>   though the compiler now normally uses
>   an integrated preprocessor.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this in QT Creator? Plus I'm using Mingw, which might be different than G++, but I don't think it should be. I'm using QT Creator and mingw on Windows if that helps.

Comment: I just edit the post, take a look. And, after using that in the .pro file, I couldn't find where the logs were saved at, and there were no .i files in the build directory. I'm not sure if they're supposed to be somewhere else or what.

Answer (score 0):

`__typeof__` is an extension of the GCC compiler, and used by CURL. That means that GCC will compiler CURL code, but other C++ parsers (such as Qt Creator) will choke on CURL code. Annoying, but not critical.

The second failure "collect2: Id returned 1 exit status" doesn't include a cause; you should quote that seprately. The reason I'd expect is that you forgot to link to the CURL library, but that's just an educated guess.

Comment: No, the typeof will only be used by curl headers if gcc is used. As a quick read of the headers will tell you...

Comment: A quick read of the error message above tells me that your assumption is wrong. Really, the code in CURL only tests whether the standard defines of GCC are present.

Comment: What do you mean linked to the CURL library? I included the necessary header files, but it's still not working.

Comment: The curl headers checks several __GNU_C_* defines to make sure that they identify a correct version. If another compiler implement these defines and then does a poor job of emulating gcc then I consider that a compiler bug and nothing else.